# How to Loop Through an Array and Create Tables in a Microsoft Access Database?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, ms-access, foreach

I have an array named `tickerArray` with five ticker symbols in it.  For each ticker symbol in `tickerArray` I need to create a table in my Microsoft Access Database.  I need each table to be named for its respective ticker symbol.  I know how to create the tables through vb.net but I run into trouble when it comes to naming each table.  As you can see in my code below I try something like `For Each tickerValue in tickerArray` and then I try and use `tickerValue` to name each table respectively.  But the code below creates the first table and names it "tickerValue" and then when it creates the second table it throws and error stating that there is already a table in the database named "tickerValue".  Any ideas on how to name each table after each ticker symbol?  Thanks in advance!

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Public Shared tickerArray() As String = {"GOOG", "V", "AAPL", "BBBY", "AMZN"}

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each tickerValue In tickerArray
        'connection string
        Dim my_connection As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\database\customers.mdb"

        'query string
        Dim my_query As String = "CREATE TABLE tickerValue ( Customer_Number Counter)"

        'create a connection
        Dim my_dbConnection As New OleDbConnection(my_connection)

        'create a command
        Dim my_Command As New OleDbCommand(my_query, my_dbConnection)

        'connection open
        my_dbConnection.Open()

        'command execute
        my_Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'close connection
        my_dbConnection.Close()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you feel you need a new table rather than setting a field to the ticker number?

Comment: That would be `Dim my_query As String = "CREATE TABLE [" &  tickerValue & "] ( Customer_Number Counter)"`

Comment: Because each table will multiple fields representing different data and multiple rows representing different dates.  Also, in the future I will have to many tickers to make this possible.

Comment: You reckon too many tables is better than too many rows?

Comment: That was exaclty what I needed thanks!  I originally planned on putting all of my information into one large table with many rows but I began reading about normalizing databases and it seemed to point me towards a table for each ticker symbol.

Comment: @Remou is wildly correct.  As long as every ticker table is going to have the same columns, you would be far better off to simply have one table and add an additional ticker symbol column to it.

Comment: No, you've misunderstood what you read about normalization.  Creating a separate table like that for each ticker symbol would definitely not be considered normalized.

Comment: I'm glad you both brought this up because this was my original plan.  The reason I began to go against my original plan was because I plan to load each stocks open and close price for each day it has existed.  This will leave me with hundreds of rows for each ticker and if I add an additional ticker symbol column I will have hundreds of rows that have the same ticker symbol in the first column.  From what I read this appears to go against the third normal form of database normalization.

Comment: No, it would not. The only thing you could do to improve it would be to create a table of tickers and put an ID for each ticker, but they are already symbols, so this may not be necessary.

Comment: What will then be my primary key?  The ticker symbol and the date combined?

Comment: Yes, or an autonumber.

Comment: Right, you don't want to repeat the same data, such as the description of the ticker symbol, over and over again, but it's totally acceptable and expected that you would repeat the identifier, such as the ticker symbol.  If you needed to store more information about each ticker symbol, such as the description, date added, etc., then you'd definitely want a separate ticker symbol table that stored all the information only once about each symbol.

Comment: @StevenDoggart That makes sense.  Thank you for clearing this up for me.  I'm just beginning to try and integrate databases with my program and I'm still trying to grasp everything.  I believe I am going have to ask a separate about how to add my ticker symbol next to each line that I import from a .csv file.  I hope you might be able to take a look at it when I do!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably listen to everyone who is telling you this is a bad idea.

But your problem is a bug caused by inserting the name of the variable into you SQL rather than the value held in the variable:

Change this:

```
'query string
Dim my_query As String = "CREATE TABLE tickerValue ( Customer_Number Counter)"
```

To this:

```
'query string
Dim my_query As String = String.Format("CREATE TABLE [{0}] ( Customer_Number Counter)", tickerValue)
```